# vim highlight (color) parentheses

Tags: vim

I have tried to put the following in my .vimrc file:

```
syn match parens /[(){}]/
hi parens ctermfg=red
```

to permanently color brackets, parentheses, braces etc, however it doesnt work. If I do it inline inside vim it does work.

Any ideas why?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because all syntax highlighting is local to the buffer that is active when the syntax items are defined.  Try something like this:

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile * syn match parens /[(){}]/ | hi parens ctermfg=red
```

Comment: Perfect answer. In my copy I replaced `BufRead,BufNewFile` with `VimEnter` and put the hi line in my colors file. Beeyouteefull.

Comment: Maybe I should say, `VimEnter,BufWinEnter`. That's what finally got it working for me both when I opened vim and when using `:e filename`.

Answer (score 4):

[Rainbow Parenthesis](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1230)
Highlight matching parens in a rainbow of colors